# A BibTeX for Reference-Style Links in Markdown?

Tags: software, references

Both [Daring Fireball](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) and [Markdown Guide](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#formatting-links) suggest that in Markdown writing, reference-style links can be put at the end of the document (say) or right after the reference is made. My question arises when you might want to use those same links across different documents. You could, of course, copy and paste them into each document, but that's logically not as good as keeping them all in just one central place, where they can be commonly updated and managed, and then just being able to refer to the needed links from different Markdown documents.

If these references weren't links, but were full-blown bibliographic references, then BibTeX or Zotero might be used. But that seems a bit heavy-handed — for one thing, you'd then also have to go to Pandoc and friends to process the references. I'm thinking of something much more lightweight, just Markdown to Markdown.

Has anyone out there developed a workflow or tool that uses common reference-style links across Markdown documents? A BibTeX for URLs in Markdown?